# JSON structure quesiton: multiple and different JSON entries, one txt file

Tags: json, logging, ndjson

I am trying to do some work with log visualization tools (Elastic and/or Splunk), but first I need to produce and format the log files from a simulation I am writing. My question, which I can't seem to find clear guidance on is:

1. How to store multiple, what I believe are root element JSON entries in a single text file
2. How to work with nested JSON structures

I am ultimately trying to have every entry follow the same form:

```
{"entry_id": 1,
 "TIME": "12:00:12Z012/01/2022",
 "LOG_TYPE":"ERROR_REPORT",
 "DATA": {
          "FIELD A" : "ABC",
          "FIELD B" : "DEF"
         }
},
{"entry_id": 2,
 "TIME": "12:15:12Z012/01/2022",
 "LOG_TYPE":"STATUS_REPORT",
 "DATA": {
          "FIELD C" : "HIJ",
          "FIELD D" : 123
         }
}
```

#### Some options I saw

1. Use an array []
2. Use NDJSON
3. Use some log template??

Any insight would be helpful

Comment: What language / platform and logging framework are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

JSON files need to be a single object and can't be INVALID themselves.

Option 1: Create a single file for each of the objects, using a numeric naming system for the files, then iterating over the files in your method.

Option 2: Create a single file but have each entry contained in an array eg:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "entry_id": 1,
      "TIME": "12:00:12Z012/01/2022",
      "LOG_TYPE": "ERROR_REPORT",
      "DATA": {
        "FIELD A": "ABC",
        "FIELD B": "DEF"
      }
    },
    {
      "entry_id": 2,
      "TIME": "12:15:12Z012/01/2022",
      "LOG_TYPE": "STATUS_REPORT",
      "DATA": {
        "FIELD C": "HIJ",
        "FIELD D": 123
      }
    }
  ]
}
```